# Building a Chrome extension that can be activated by hotkeys

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, hotkeys

Which Chrome API allows me to write an extension which can be activated by non-conflicting hotkeys (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>), or by trackpad gesture (on Mac)?

I'm looking at [Chrome extension API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) and [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/developers) docs, but haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keyboard shortcuts can be added using the *manifest.json* key [`commands`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands). You can add keyboard shortcuts for generic actions, for your browser action button (`_execute_browser_action`), or your page action button (`_execute_page_action`).

The example *manifest.json* content that is included in the [Chrome documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) is (slightly modified to reflect your request for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>):

```json
"commands": {
  "toggle-feature-foo": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "default": "Ctrl+Shift+B",
      "mac": "Command+Shift+B"
    },
    "description": "Toggle feature foo"
  },
  "_execute_browser_action": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "windows": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
      "mac": "Command+Shift+Y",
      "chromeos": "Ctrl+Shift+U",
      "linux": "Ctrl+Shift+J"
    }
  },
  "_execute_page_action": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "default": "Ctrl+Shift+E",
      "windows": "Alt+Shift+P",
      "mac": "Alt+Shift+P"
    }
  }
},
```

`toggle-feature-foo` is generic. You can change that *manifest.json" key to be what you desire. It is passed as the argument to your `chrome.commands.onCommand` listener.

In your background script you can then have (modified from same source):

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
    console.log('Command:', command);
    if(command === 'toggle-feature-foo') {
        //Code for toggle-feature-foo
    }
});
```

Unless the Mac trackpad gesture also generates a keyboard key sequence, there is no way to easily capture such gestures. You might be able to write a content script that did so. However, if you had to use a content script to do so, that would probably be a significant burden on every web page just to enable that feature.

Comment: Thanks so much. On top of your mind, can I configure the hotkeys to overlap with Chrome built-in hotkeys (like using Ctrl+Shift+T) ? Anyway, this is exactly what I look for.

Comment: Also, users can change them at chrome://extensions/configureCommands