# How do you trigger a chrome extension via a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I wrote a short chrome extension that works as intended when I click on it on my extension list.

Ie. my code runs `onClicked` (`chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(...)`)

I would like to add a keyboard shortcut (eg. Ctrl+Shift+Q) but not sure how.

Any ideas?

For context: I don't really know javascript, I'm hacking this together as a helper for myself in my day to day work.

Comment: For ManifestV2 extension see [Building a Chrome extension that can be activated by hotkeys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41002202)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a command.

First step is to add the command to the manifest.json file.  I added an example down below it should look very similar to your, but the part you really need is the "commands": {} section.  This tells chrome to pay attention to when a user hits "Ctrl+Shift+Q".  Note you can add multiple commands, like in the example below.

```
{
  "name": "Getting Started Example",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },

  "devtools_page": "devtools.html",

  "commands": {
    "name-of-command-passed-into-function": {
      "suggested_key": "Ctrl+Shift+Q",
      "description": "do somthing"
    }
    "shortcut2": {
      "suggested_key": "Ctrl+Shift+A",
      "description": "do somthing else"
    }
  },
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting","tabs"],
}
```

Now when the user hits "Ctrl+Shift+Q" or "Ctrl+Shift+A", chrome will loos for some very specific code to run:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((command,tab) => {
     //do stuff here
});
```

Add this code and change the //do stuff here, to the code you want to run.  The command property will simply be a string that matches what was types into the manifest, "name-of-command-passed-into-function" or "shortcut2".  This is how you tell which command shortcut the user entered, but if you only need one, then delete the second one from the manifest file.